# netbeans git support: difference between 'ignore' and 'exclude from commit'

Tags: git, netbeans

I am a new git user. I want to exclude my local wamp database settings when pushing changes to my website with git. I am using netbeans and I want to add my config directory to a gitignore file. Does anyone know how to do this using netbeans built in git support.

Thanks,

Bill

Comment: Why through Netbeans? It's very easy to add to the `.gitignore` file, just add `/config/`.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it, and it turns out that selecting 'ignore' will add the selected directory/file to the .gitignore file.

Hope this helps someone. - Bill

Comment: But what's the difference between "ignore" and "exclude from commit"?